# c++ linking a 3rd party header and source

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, tinyxml

I'm attempting to integrate [TinyXML version 2](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2) into a project, but because TinyXML is so tiny (ha!) it was not packaged into a static or dynamic library. Just the header and source is provided. I am getting linker errors because the compiler can't find the source file to link with the header (they are in the same location).

Is there a way to link a 3rd party source into a project without having to copy it into the local project space?

OR

Should I manually create a library file (containing a single source file) and just use that to work around the problem (even though the source not changing is a good reason to package it, it seems overkill for one file)?

[See tags]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want it in your local project space, you seem to be treating it as a library, at least conceptually.

Build the library file once and never worry about it again.

The number of source files in a library shouldn't concern you.

Answer (score 0):

Include `tinyxml2.cpp` instead of `tinyxml2.h`.
Or you can build `.lib` file, include `.h` file and tell linker to use your `.lib`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, build an ad-hoc static library by simply #including the .cpp files in a single translation unit. This might be frowned upon by some, but it's an easy solution that also has its advantages.